# 'take' or 'make' before certain nouns

Tags: word-choice

I often have to think before I choose ***take*** or ***make*** in front of nouns like *a step, a decision, a picture*, and I am pretty sure this happens because of my mother tongue. Are all these simply idiomatic expressions which we eventually get used to through practice, or is there some kind of guiding rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are very different words and there are relatively few cases where, due to idiomatic use, they can both be used. "Step" and "decision" are examples of this.

"**Make**" means to *produce* or *create* something. One can '*make* a step' in that they created that action.

"**Take**" (in this context) means to *do* or begin to do something (see also '*undertake*') so a person can also be said to '*take* a step' in that they carried out that action. It is idiomatic to this particular context, but there are other examples where it is idiomatic such as 'taking decisions'.

Your example of a 'picture' is different - it is idiomatic to say "take a picture" if you mean a *photograph*, but not to say you "made" a photograph. However, when it comes to other forms of art that you actually create or construct, you could use "made".

I can't say there is any firm guiding rule, but if you keep in mind the root meaning of 'made' is to *create* you will see where that might be inappropriate. Note also that there are other definitions of 'take'. It can mean *to seize* something, for example, you can "take a holiday" or "take a break".

Comment: "Take a picture" relates to the idea that the picture exists and the camera siezes it, making it permanent.

Comment: 'make or take a guess'? According to your explanation then, 'to make a mistake' (can't use 'take' here definitely) is idiomatic, right?

Comment: "take a holiday" or "take a break" makes me think that you can replace 'take' with 'have' in these 2 particular cases. So can I also say 'take' or 'have a shower'?

Comment: @fev you're absolutely correct, you can have a holiday (or 'vacation' in US English). You can have a shower, or take a shower.

Comment: Beautiful, I feel a bit more confident :)

Comment: @fev If you consider the meaning of *to undertake*, that's a bit clearer - it means to carry out, or to **do** a process or a procedure - like having a shower.

Comment: @ Astralbee (beautiful user name) oooooh, if you tell me _DO_ I enter another realm of uncertainty :) . DO or MAKE a job, a mistake, a comment. Problem is, in my mother tongue there is only one word for both... But I love pinning down idioms, because this is so specific to my target language!